# SQL dividing column by a number in another table

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

```
total_table = 
| Title | Value |
|-------|-------|
| total |   20  |

breakdown_table =
|  Title | Value |
|--------|-------|
|  total |   20  | (this is the same as the above table)
| type a |   10  |
| type b |    5  |
| type c |    5  |
```

I would like to create a new table which includes both columns from `breakdown_table` but adds a 3rd column that shows the breakdown percentages (100%, 50%, 25%, 25%). How can I do this without hardcoding the denominator?

Here's some syntax I've tried but it keeps giving me errors about commas and equijoin. I'm not trying to join the tables with a key, I just want to use the single value in the `total_table`.

```
data_out = SELECT breakdown_table.*,
                  breakdown_table.Value / total.Value
           FROM breakdown_table, total_table;
```

Comment: _generally_, it's preferred to not store aggregated information (the `total` column), and especially not in the table (rollup tables are occasionally necessary, although it's better to automate them when possible).  That said, I'm more curious about the fact you seem to have a global value here....

Comment: I'm not quite following. The above is just a snippet of my code. Which value did you think was global? Also what do you mean by "preferred not to store aggregated information"? Did you mean I shouldn't have the total_table as a separate table? (Also, changed table names for clarity).

Comment: Unless you have specific performance issues (identified by monitoring, and usually due to databases with 1Mil+ rows in tables), it's best to avoid storing derived information (which includes things like totals), in preference for calculating them as part of queries or views.  So, no, you probably don't want `total_table`, or the `total` row in the breakdown table; you probably do want one or more _views_ that will return the same information.  Maintaining aggregate tables is dangerous in the face of failure and concurrency problems.

Comment: The "global value" is the data in the `total_table` - by cross-joining like you need to, you're implying there will only ever be one row in the table (and that `breakdown_table` will only ever have one "set" of rows, not rows from two different transactions or whatever).  This seems strange, and isn't how tables are usually used in a database (possibly as a temp table in a stored procedure, but even then...).  So it makes me worry that you're headed into [X-Y Problem territory](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/256219).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cross join the tables (properly):

```
SELECT 
  b.*, 
  100.0 * b.Value / t.Value as data_out
FROM breakdown as b cross join total as t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using cross join:

```
select t1.Title, t1.Value, 100 * t1.Value / t2.Value AS BPCT
from mytable t1
cross join mytable t2
where t2.Title = "total"
```

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to other answers here but will get you the percentages in the right format.

```
select t1.*, format(t1.value/1.0/t2.value,'P0') as pcnt
from breakdown_table t1 cross apply total_table t2
```

If you wish to use the implicit join method, then you need to change the column name in total_table

```
select t1.*,format(value*1.0/total,'P0') as pcnt
from breakdown_table t1,(select value as total from total_table) t2
```